# Infragistics: the type exists in both location

Tags: infragistics

I get this error. My program files contains CLR3.0 and CLR4.0. I have tried to remove the CLR3.0 folder but then another error is coming out.

This is the error message displayed when have both CLR3.0 and CLR4.0 folder:

> The type 'Infragistics.Windows.Editors.ComboBoxItemsProvider' exists in both 'c:\Program Files\Infragistics\NetAdvanatage 2011.1\WPF\CLR3.0\Bin\InfragisticsWPF3.Editors.v11.2.dll' and 'c:\Users\myname\Documents\Project\Projects\Ion\Ion\Dev\ThirdParty\InfragisticsWPF4.Editors.v11.2.dll'

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is because both the 3.0 and 4.0 assembly are being loaded.  Since both versions of the assembly have the same types, the compiler doesn't know which one to use.

To fix this you will need to remove all references to the 3.0 assemblies.  Check both your references and references for each dependency.